# Solidity compile Error: Expected primary expression. }

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to compile a contract in the [solidity browser compiler](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js)
and get this error:

> Untitled:19:9: Error: Expected primary expression.
>   
>         }
>   
>         ^

Is this due to the `throw;` statement?

```
contract user {

    address public owner;

    function user(){
        owner = msg.sender;
        }

    function kill(){
        suicide(owner);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner{
        if (msg.sender != owner){
            throw;
        }else{
            -
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your modified code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract user {

    address public owner;

    function user() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function kill() {
        suicide(owner);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) {
            throw;
        } else {
            _;
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem with your code is that I had to replace your `-` with a `_;`. See [Are underscores `_` in modifiers code or are they just meant to look cool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/are-underscores-in-modifiers-code-or-are-they-just-meant-to-look-cool) for more information on the `_` modifiers.

Your modified code then compiles perfectly in the Solidity realtime compiler and runtime:

[image]