# How to call Library Function from a Contract? => [error] The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-deployment, gas-limit, homestead

When I compiled following code at "https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/" it gives me two Web3 deploy code for:

```
var libraryContract  = web3.eth.contract(...); //Web3 deploy code
var contractContract = web3.eth.contract(...); //Web3 deploy code
```

Then I have copy paste Web3 deploy code for (libraryContract, contractContract) into geth in order to mine my contracts.

My code (I have trimmed most of it for simplicity):

```
library Library {
    function func () constant returns (uint8) {
        return 5;
    }
}

contract Contract {
    uint8 value;
    function call_library_function () {
        value = Library.func();
    }
}
```

"Library"'s Web3 deploy code mines perfectly fine, 
but when I try to mine "Contract"'s Web3 deploy code, I get the following error:

**> Error: The contract code couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount. undefined**

If I remove the following line from my Contract Link code, newly generated "Contract"'s Web3 deploy code mines! without any problem:

```
value = Library.func();
```

[Q] My question is, how could I fix this problem I am having? What should I do to call my function inside a Library from a Contract, which will allow me to mine it?

**How I did setup my private Ethereum Blockchain:**
Please see on the following link:
[How could I update default homesteadBlock value on my private Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9240/4575)

Thank you for your valuable help and time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Library contract method failing #2831](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2831):

> You probably run geth with the --dev option to create a private network? In that case use the init subcommand to create a private chain. Instructions can be found in the wiki. Or use the testnet.
>
> The problem is that this code uses the **delegatecall** which is **added in the homestead release**. The --dev flag uses the homestead block number of the mainnet which is **1150000**. **Any transaction before this block will encounter an invalid opcode, consumes all gas and all state changes are reverted.**

To work around this issue:

> ...
>
> The genesis config file supports a config section. Currently the only thing you can **configure** is the **homestead block number**. If you don't specify it, it will be defaulted to the mainnet number which is 1150000. So basically your contract will work after this block.
>
> Try the following genesis file:
>
> ```
> {
>   "config":{
>      "homesteadBlock":"5"
>   },
>   "nonce":"0x0000000000000042",
>   "timestamp":"0x0",
>   "parentHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>   "extraData":"0x0",
>   "gasLimit":"0x8000000",
>   "difficulty":"0x400",
>   "mixhash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
>   "coinbase":"0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
>   "alloc":{
>
>   }
> ```
>
> }
>
> If the contract is deployed in block <5 it will give the gas limit problem.
>
> Deployed in block >= 5 it should work as intended.

Further information on using the genesis file can be found at [geth init, what are the arguments?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2643/1268).

---

### Update 10:33 Oct 14 2016

I have set up my private blockchain using the following procedures:

### 1. Setup genesis.json

```
Wocket:ESE bok$ more genesis.json 
{
    "config": {
            "homesteadBlock": 10
    },
    "nonce": "0",
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
    "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x3B4A1B44",
    "alloc": {}
}
```

### 2. Password file

I created a password file `testpassword` containing my account password

### 3. Blockchain Initialisation Script

I created a script to initialise my blockchain:

```
Wocket:ESE bok$ more 02_runGethGenesisInit 
#!/bin/sh

geth --datadir /Users/bok/ESE/gethgenesis init /Users/bok/ESE/genesis.json
geth --datadir /Users/bok/ESE/gethgenesis --password testpassword account new
```

And I used `chmod 700 02_runGethGenesisInit` to set the executable bit.

### 4. Private Node Script

I created a script to start my private `geth` node in mining mode:

```
Wocket:ESE bok$ more 02_runGethGenesis 
#!/bin/sh

geth --datadir /Users/bok/ESE/gethgenesis --unlock 0 --password /Users/bok/ESE/testpassword --rpc --rpccorsdomain '*' --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

And I used `chmod 700 02_runGethGenesis` to set the executable bit.

### 5. Browser Solidity

I downloaded [Browser Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/blob/gh-pages/browser-solidity-ed07413.zip) from https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/tree/gh-pages.

I unzipped the files and loaded `index.html` into my web browser.

### 6. Start it all

I initialised my blockchain data using the following command:

```
Wocket:ESE bok$ ./02_runGethGenesisInit
```

I started my node using the following command, and have been running it for a while:

```
Wocket:ESE bok$ ./02_runGethGenesis
...
I1015 09:56:14.364062 miner/worker.go:342]   Mined block (#5210 / f881b1be). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I1015 09:56:14.364333 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 5211 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 281.474µs
I1015 09:56:14.364360 miner/worker.go:435]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #5205
I1015 09:56:14.364492 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 5211 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 114.592µs
I1015 09:56:16.394886 miner/worker.go:342]   Mined block (#5211 / 420c7edc). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
I1015 09:56:16.395189 miner/worker.go:539] commit new work on block 5212 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 262.993µs
I1015 09:56:16.395222 miner/worker.go:435]    Mined 5 blocks back: block #5206
```

### 7. Testing For The Homestead Mode

I loaded the test script by `@TjadenHess` from [How could I update default homesteadBlock value on my private Ethereum blockchain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9240/how-could-i-update-default-homesteadblock-value-on-my-private-ethereum-blockchai) into Solidity Browser:

```
contract TestHomestead{
    function test () returns(bool){
        return address(4).delegatecall(1);
    }
}
```

I connected Solidity Browser to my local private node by clicking on the block icon and selecting **Web3 Provider**. I then clicked on **Create** to deploy the contract above to the blockchain. I clicked **test** and the message `Transaction cost: 21657 gas.` shows that my blockchain is in Homestead mode.

[image]

[image]

Note: If I alter the function to make it a constant `function test () constant returns(bool){`, I get the following results for a Homestead mode blockchain - **true**:

[image]

See section 9. below for the message displayed when the blockchain is in non-Homestead mode.

### 8. Testing The Library Call Source Code

I've modified the library call source code slightly to make the `value` variable public, and loaded this into Browser Solidity :

```
library Library {
    function func () constant returns (uint8) {
        return 5;
    }
}

contract Contract {
    uint8 public value;
    function call_library_function () {
        value = Library.func();
    }
}
```

I clicked **Create** to deploy the code, **call_library_function** to execute the method, and **value** to view the library call function result:

[image]

[image]

## Success

The message `Transaction cost: 41914 gas.` and the value of `value` shows that the library function call succeeded.

### 9. What Happens When My Node Is In Non-Homestead Mode

I connected Browser Solidity with a `geth --dev` blockchain:

```
geth --dev --datadir /Users/bok/ESE/gethdata --unlock 0 --password /Users/bok/ESE/testpassword --rpc --rpccorsdomain '*' --mine --minerthreads 1 console
```

I ran the same Homestead test code to produce the message **Gas required exceeds limit: 50000000** showing that this `--dev` blockchain is in non-Homestead mode:

[image]

Note: If I alter the function to make it a constant `function test () constant returns(bool){`, I get the following results for a non-Homestead mode blockchain - **false**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir. Did it worked with you when gas Limit is updated as 5000000?

Comment: Sorry. My Browser Solidity is offline at the moment. Rebuilding my notebook as an software upgrade caused it to stop working. Deploy your contract without the `list.append("abc","111"); ` and check how much gas it takes. Then add 10% more and see if this solves your problem.

I note that you are writing your code and then deploying into `geth` directly. You should be able to connect Browser Solidity to your local `geth` instance by selecting the Web3 Provider in the third icon from the left - refer to the screen image in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8970/1268.

Comment: Ok I am trying your suggestion. I am running geth on my private ethereum blockchain. I have  forced to run geth -targetgaslimit "994712388". My gas limit increasing from 470000, right now at 500000. Solidity browser always give 470000 for the gas usage, so I am updating it manually the "gas: <int>" value for the contract. Hopefully I will find a gas that the contract will be mined.

Comment: I you want to deploy via `geth`, see the step-by-step guide http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2751/deploying-the-greeter-contract-via-the-geth-cli-is-not-registering-in-my-private for an example on how to specify gas for the contract deployment.

Comment: I updated gas limit up to "15529600", still same error.

Comment: I have done suggestion but again it seems like it won't work. I am still working on it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link for using the genesis file.

Comment: Thank you sir, based on your guidance I have updated my question how I created my private Ethereum blockchain. But still it gives me the same error. Is there anything wrong about how I created my private ethereum blockchain?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a step-by-step guide to deploying the library function call successfully.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I appreciate your valuable help. I am working on it to make it work on my side.

Comment: Well it works!!

Comment: Is it possible to do your answer also using `solc`? @BokkyPooBah

Comment: @Avatar, see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11031/1268

Comment: Would it be possible to update your answer with new solidity browser? Solidity-browser's GUI has been changed and I am not able to deploy my contract through it :( @BokkyPooBah