# Why does having multiple functions with events prevent proper execution?

Tags: private-blockchain, events, logs

I am relatively new to Ethereum, so I apologize if there is an obvious answer to this question.

I am running a private blockchain to test contracts on. I have a very simple one, where there is one member variable and one event defined. Then there are 2 functions, where each one calls the event with a single argument. With only these two functions, the events work properly. When I call "sendTransaction" on either function, there is a event log in the Transaction Receipt.

However, when I add a 3rd function, that is just as simple (all it does is call the event on a single argument), then all 3 functions stop working properly. They no longer show up in the Transaction Receipt.

I have even tried giving the transaction more gas, but it uses up all the gas I supply and still no even appears in the receipt.

Does any know why this happens?

Contact Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0; 
contract SetADT{ 
    struct VoterLog {
        address senderAccount;
        uint256 time;
        uint blockNumber;
    }
    mapping(uint => VoterLog) voterStatus;
    mapping(uint => uint128) voterKeys;
    uint voterIndex;

    mapping(address => bool) validNodes;

    mapping(uint => bool) contractSet; 
    event Print(bool); 
    event PrintAddr(address);

    function setTrue(uint key) external { 
        if(contractSet[key] == false) { 
            contractSet[key] = true;
        } 
        Print(contractSet[key]); 
    } 

    function getValue(uint key) external { 
        Print(contractSet[key]); 
    } 
}
```

When I add the following function as the third function in the contract, the events stop working (showing up in the transaction receipt).

```
function setAddr() {
    validNodes[msg.sender] = true;
    Print(validNodes[msg.sender]);
}
```

I have also test each individual function on their own in a separate contract, and they work fine. This leads me to believe that there is no error in the function code.

Thank you in advanced for any help!

Comment: Could you please add some sample code to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Please edit the question and add include the formatted source code. One source code snippet is worth of 1000 English words.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be able to tell you *why* it's happening without looking at the source, but I might be able tell you *what.*

Any abnormal end appears as a out-of-gas error. (This includes `throw`, going out of bounds with an array, division by zero, paying a non-`payable` function, etc.) When this happens, everything is reverted, including any events that might have occurred. If you keep adding gas with no success, then it's most likely one of those things.

EDIT:

I tried putting the full contract in [Browser-Solidity](https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-v0.4.7+commit.822622cf.js&optimize=undefined&gist=https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f8c2ec8da49eb77b91cccddbb7697c5c) and the events seemed to work fine.

However, the full, three-function contract uses much more gas when created. It might be possible that the initial transaction creating it is going out-of-gas, in which case no events will be happening, period. You could make sure using [web3.eth.getCode()](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode).

Comment: Thank you for this information. Unfortunately, I am not sure what the error might be in my code since all the functions are very simple. I will update my post with the code

Answer (score 1):

Your contract runs perfectly on my private blockchain using `geth` and [Browser Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/tree/gh-pages) that I downloaded to run locally and connect to `geth` on http://localhost:8545 .

#### Deployment And Execution In Browser Solidity

Here is a screen showing the deployment ("Create") of the contract and the execution of `setTrue(...)` using 43,324 gas and the event result `true`:
[image]

Here is a screen showing the execution of `getValue(...)` using 22,901 gas and the second event result `true`:
[image]

Here is a screen showing the execution of `setAddr()` using 27,867 gas and the third event result `true`:
[image]

#### Deployment And Executing In Geth Using Browser Solidity Generated Code

Following is the code from the Web3 Deploy box in Browser Solidity:

```
var setadtContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"key","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getValue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"key","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setTrue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"setAddr","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"","type":"bool"}],"name":"Print","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"PrintAddr","type":"event"}]);
var setadt = setadtContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Here are the results of pasting the code above into the `geth` console:

```
> var setadtContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"key","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getValue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"key","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setTrue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"setAddr","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":fa
undefined
> 
... 
...... 
......      data: '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
...... 
...... 
......     
...... 
......... 
......... 
......  })
I0111 13:29:52.055310 internal/ethapi/api.go:1045] Tx(0x30eedc837b40897b7ec5ac914b30bed3307333dcba12e70d4840b7e0bd8d5c86) created: 0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc
null [object Object]
undefined
> I0111 13:29:54.085918 miner/unconfirmed.go:105]   mined block #4704 [6c46e8d2…] reached canonical chain
I0111 13:29:54.085955 miner/unconfirmed.go:83]   mined potential block #4709 [6cc54975…], waiting for 5 blocks to confirm
I0111 13:29:54.087158 miner/worker.go:516] commit new work on block 4710 with 1 txs & 0 uncles. Took 1.210405ms
I0111 13:29:57.645780 miner/unconfirmed.go:105]   mined block #4705 [c9b78f22…] reached canonical chain
I0111 13:29:57.645928 miner/unconfirmed.go:83]   mined potential block #4710 [54b88d79…], waiting for 5 blocks to confirm
I0111 13:29:57.646092 miner/worker.go:516] commit new work on block 4711 with 0 txs & 0 uncles. Took 336.529µs
null [object Object]
Contract mined! address: 0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc transactionHash: 0x30eedc837b40897b7ec5ac914b30bed3307333dcba12e70d4840b7e0bd8d5c86
```

Here's the execution of `setTrue(...)` in `geth`:

```
> var tx = setadt.setTrue(1234, {from: eth.accounts[0]});
I0111 13:37:01.968067 internal/ethapi/api.go:1047] Tx(0xcbca2eedeaab28b3447648651b3b18118e644bbcb48c5fb4923fef52d76102b2) to: 0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc
...
> eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx)
{
  blockHash: "0x479f7ee50c7568c92e48b1dbdcfe6f90e6e349ade6f9148abb1f7630f9954f0c",
  blockNumber: 4771,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 43324,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 43324,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc",
      blockHash: "0x479f7ee50c7568c92e48b1dbdcfe6f90e6e349ade6f9148abb1f7630f9954f0c",
      blockNumber: 4771,
      data: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0x2b3980e1f246a34892c233a6b281a346c73168eed33a17c643f090ce730156b3"],
      transactionHash: "0xcbca2eedeaab28b3447648651b3b18118e644bbcb48c5fb4923fef52d76102b2",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000001000000000000",
  root: "0x06937bb7d67fd4a8e18ab013d76218ffab8c7d339f71f4f3bace02e8b0e56e1b",
  to: "0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc",
  transactionHash: "0xcbca2eedeaab28b3447648651b3b18118e644bbcb48c5fb4923fef52d76102b2",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

Let's retrieve the event log information, where you can see the `true` result:

```
var printEvent = setadt.Print({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
printEvent.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
...
{"address":"0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc","args":{"":true},"blockHash":"0x479f7ee50c7568c92e48b1dbdcfe6f90e6e349ade6f9148abb1f7630f9954f0c","blockNumber":4771,"event":"Print","logIndex":0,"removed":false,"transactionHash":"0xcbca2eedeaab28b3447648651b3b18118e644bbcb48c5fb4923fef52d76102b2","transactionIndex":0}
```

And here is the execution of `setAddr()` and the resulting events:

```
> var tx2 = setadt.setAddr({from: eth.accounts[0]});
I0111 13:43:40.814744 internal/ethapi/api.go:1047] Tx(0xa7317bc32128513df91aa45da6ec583b78904275d55457e1f8651b203d2c6c7b) to: 0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc
...
> eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx2);
{
  blockHash: "0xf5e9060cffa08aa76ed14f978e34412aa57d3fa459a178e50498c62b2e8d54dc",
  blockNumber: 4811,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 42867,
  from: "0x000d1009bd8f0b1301cc5edc28ed1222a3ce671e",
  gasUsed: 42867,
  logs: [{
      address: "0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc",
      blockHash: "0xf5e9060cffa08aa76ed14f978e34412aa57d3fa459a178e50498c62b2e8d54dc",
      blockNumber: 4811,
      data: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
      logIndex: 0,
      removed: false,
      topics: ["0x2b3980e1f246a34892c233a6b281a346c73168eed33a17c643f090ce730156b3"],
      transactionHash: "0xa7317bc32128513df91aa45da6ec583b78904275d55457e1f8651b203d2c6c7b",
      transactionIndex: 0
  }],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080000000000001000000000000",
  root: "0xea4839d4e6a4f4cb0873506bb57cc566f38833ed3593f4e02a0c6e4cf55cc726",
  to: "0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc",
  transactionHash: "0xa7317bc32128513df91aa45da6ec583b78904275d55457e1f8651b203d2c6c7b",
  transactionIndex: 0
}

> var printEvent = setadt.Print({}, {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest'});
undefined
> printEvent.watch(function(error, result){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
...
{"address":"0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc","args":{"":true},"blockHash":"0x479f7ee50c7568c92e48b1dbdcfe6f90e6e349ade6f9148abb1f7630f9954f0c","blockNumber":4771,"event":"Print","logIndex":0,"removed":false,"transactionHash":"0xcbca2eedeaab28b3447648651b3b18118e644bbcb48c5fb4923fef52d76102b2","transactionIndex":0}
{"address":"0x4ebb8365205f6096decbe0fcfcae91db164359bc","args":{"":true},"blockHash":"0xf5e9060cffa08aa76ed14f978e34412aa57d3fa459a178e50498c62b2e8d54dc","blockNumber":4811,"event":"Print","logIndex":0,"removed":false,"transactionHash":"0xa7317bc32128513df91aa45da6ec583b78904275d55457e1f8651b203d2c6c7b","transactionIndex":0}
```

Comment: I was testing the contract solely on the geth console. I never used the Solidity Browser before. Could you please explain how you set up your private network so that I could try to recreate the results you got?

Comment: Here's how I set up my private network for `geth` - http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-call-library-function-from-a-contract-error-the-contract-code-could/9181#9181 . To connect Browser Solidity to `geth`, make sure `geth` has `--rpc` enabled. In BS, click on Environment (third cube icon from left on the top), then click on Web3 Provider. If you cannot get it working, please ask a new Question like "How do I set up a private network connected to Browser Solidity?" and I'll document it.