# How to unlock account in ethereum where Transaction are too higher?

Tags: go-ethereum, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic, ethereumj

While working on the ethereum , I come out with the issue of out of memory because of multiple transaction execution concurrently . The main reason was , i was unlocking account of that user every time which take too much of memory , if i do contract function execute (transaction) without unlocking the account in code and unlock account in geth by

> personal.unlockAccount("address","password")

and then run transaction it execute smoothly over 500 transaction / sec . How can i unlock account everytime or give me better solution how to unlock account so that i can overcome with out off memory problem ?

Comment: Refer to the usage of the password file and `--password` in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/9178/how-to-call-library-function-from-a-contract-error-the-contract-code-could/9181#9181

Comment: @BokkyPooBah can it will we possible that geth is running and when a new account create , how it can be unlock automatically . So that i have to not unlock account everytime when i run code of contract.

Comment: @BokkyPooBah `geth --unlock firstaddress,secondaddress,.. --password <passwordFile> ` will unlock all address written here and If i want the newAddress also unlock what should i do so that it will we also get unlock  .

Comment: doing that is a potential risk, you will have to figure out a way if you actually want to use this in production right?

Answer (score 0):

What about using **signed transactions**?

With [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) you can sign transaction using the public key generated by geth.

You will no longer need to either manually or programmatically unlock accounts.

You then use *web3.eth.sendRawTransaction* to submit transactions.

Comment: if i need contract and execute contract function then ?