# Code in ReentrancyGuard.sol unreachable

Tags: solidity, remix, reentrant-attacks

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

contract SavingsContract is ReentrancyGuard{

address owner;
uint8 interest = 10;

struct Savers{
    address saver;
    uint savedAmount;
    uint dateOfDeposit;
}
Savers[] public savers;

constructor(){
    owner = msg.sender;
}
modifier onlyOwner{
    owner == msg.sender;
    _;
}

function depositMoney() payable public {
    require(msg.value <= (msg.sender).balance,"Insufficient funds");
    require(msg.value >= 10000, "Need to send min 10 000 Wei");
    savers.push(Savers(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp));
}
function interestEarned() view public returns(uint){
    uint storedTime;
    for (uint i=0; i < savers.length; ++i){
        Savers storage savingsAccount = savers[i];
        if (msg.sender == savingsAccount.saver){
            storedTime = block.timestamp - savingsAccount.dateOfDeposit;
            return (savingsAccount.savedAmount);
        }
    }
}
function withdraw() external nonReentrant {
    uint storedTime;
    for (uint i=0; i < savers.length; ++i){
        Savers storage savingsAccount = savers[i];
        if (msg.sender == savingsAccount.saver){
            storedTime = block.timestamp - savingsAccount.dateOfDeposit;
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(savingsAccount.savedAmount);
            savers[i] = savers[savers.length - 1];
            savers.pop();
        }
    }
    revert("User not found!");
}

function viewContractBalance() public view returns(uint){
    return address(this).balance;
}
}
```

Hey guys, I have written a simple savings smart contract, which pays you interest for storing funds with them and I have decided to secure it against reentrancy with the ReentrancyGuard.sol library. However for some reason I get an error that the code is unreachable.
Can you please help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore that warning, the "unreachable" code is actually the initial state of the "modified" function

1.- the state of the modified withdraw function is `_NOT_ENTERED` before calling the function because the function hasn't been called

2.- once you call the function withdraw, the modifier code is executed

3.- in the modifier,  everything that is before the `_;` is executed, therefore the function state is set to `_ENTERED` making it impossible to call the function again until its execution is finished (thats the reentrancy guard in action)

```
//ReentrancyGuard contract by OpenZeppelin

modifier nonReentrant() {
    // On the first call to nonReentrant, _notEntered will be true
    require(_status != _ENTERED, "ReentrancyGuard: reentrant call");

    // Any calls to nonReentrant after this point will fail
    _status = _ENTERED;

    _; // <--- everything before this is executed

    // By storing the original value once again, a refund is triggered (see
    // https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2200)
    _status = _NOT_ENTERED;
}
```

I inspired my answer by this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5861/are-underscores-in-modifiers-code-or-are-they-just-meant-to-look-cool) and this [medium post](https://medium.com/coinmonks/the-curious-case-of-in-solidity-16d9eb4440f1)

Comment: So are you saying the the Reentrancy guard will work despite the warning?

Comment: Yes, indeed :) the magic happens within the `_;`