# what does the underscore mean in this modifier situation?

Tags: solidity, modifiers

Came across this little confusing situation of underscores in modifier so I want to post it here to check if my understanding is correct.

```
contract whatever{
    bool public locked;
    uint public x = 10;

    modifier noReentrancy() {
        require(!locked, "No reentrancy");

        locked = true;
        _;
        locked = false;
    }

    function decrement(uint i) public noReentrancy {
        x -= i;

        if (i > 1) {
            decrement(i - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

the underscore in the middle of the modifier function is little trick to me. so my understanding is: when modifier is first ran, the value of *locked* is true. then the underscore means run the function code which is *x-= i* ...
this will trigger the if condition and if i >i then the same function will be called again while being executed (the point of noReentry modifier)
then the value of locked will be false which will trigger the function *decrement()* to stop. the value of x will be 10.
so unless the value of i is 1 or 0 (so the if condition is not triggered), the value of x will always be 10 in this case?

thank you for your patience!

Comment: this is a good reading material https://medium.com/coinmonks/the-curious-case-of-in-solidity-16d9eb4440f1

Comment: btw i think this is a duplicate of this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/5861/99976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underscore represents the rest of the  function code. Whatever is before the underscore is ran before the function code, and whatever is after is ran after

( By the way, in the case where a function uses multiple modifier, they're ran in the order they're declared *in the code* (and not in the function declaration) for example :

```
modifier isA{
//...
}
modifier isB{
//...
}
function modified() isB isA external {
// isA is ran before isB
}
```

detour over, back to the answer. )

So your understanding of the modifier is correct. Your understanding of what your code does, however, isnt. Here, assuming `i > 1` when you call decrement, the beginning of the modifier will be ran, so `locked` will be set to true, then `x` will decrement, then the if() condition will evaluate to true ( i is greater than 1) which will call the function again, run the modifier code again, and  the require statement `require(!locked)` will evaluate to false since the rest of the modifier that sets `locked` back to false hasnt run yet, and the call will revert.

Comment: thank you for correcting me! now I got it!